# Why does my garage door opener only click when the button is pushed?

Tags: garage-door-opener, troubleshooting

My Quantum 3213 garage door opener only clicks when I hit the main button in the garage. The light comes on for 30 seconds or so, and then it blinks on and off.

I've checked all the safety mechanisms: the eyes are aligned, etc.

Why won't it do its thing?

Comment: Could be the motor is burned out.

Comment: See: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/70006/garage-door-stops-at-a-different-place-each-time-it-closes (different problem, but likely root cause the same - the internal computer or main board is likely bad.

Comment: I believe the light blinking my be a trouble shooting code that you may be able to decipher through the products web site.

Comment: How hard is it to open the door manually? Perhaps it is just stuck.

Comment: Make sure the aligned eyes LED status is green on both eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the door is not unhooked from the lift mechanism. On some door systems there is a rope that when pulled releases the door from the motorized lift. This would allow the door to be opened and closed by hand. If the door wasn't reconnected to the catch then the motor when activated would spin and not lift the door.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the primary motor capacitors have failed, resulting in a condition where the circuit board is calling for motor operation, but it's unable to start. Open the case and inspect the large capacitors for bulging or leaking. Test them with a multi-meter if available.

Also look for glass tube fuses on the board.

**Disconnect the power when appropriate for safety.**